How to show a different value (label) in the filter dropdown than in the column?
Is it possible to display a different value than those within a DT's column in the dropdown that allows you to filter a factor column? Ideally, I would like to render HTML within a column, but when filtering that column, see a different, corresponding label. I attempted to use factor labels, but that didn't seem to work. I'd like to use this table within a Shiny app, so I'd be happy to apply some CSS or JS tweaks to make this happen.
This example bolds the text the in table - ideally the values in the filtering dropdown would only be the values themselves, not the entire HTML tags. Is this possible?
library(dplyr)

DT::datatable(
  iris %>%
    mutate(Species = factor(Species, levels = unique(.$Species),
                            labels = paste0('<strong>', unique(.$Species), '</strong>'))),
  escape = FALSE,
  filter = 'top')

Here's an image of what I want to achieve - removing the HTML tags from the filter options:


I'm not sure what you're asking for. Are you asking about the labels on the slider, when filtering? Is there any way you could provide something that shows what you want the result to look like? (It can be drawn by hand.)

I've edited my post to include an image with lines over the tags I want to remove. Thanks!

Right now you call for paste0(... does not cause strong (bold) text, it simply adds that nonsense to your labels. Change your call for datatable labels to labels = unique(.$Species).

Right, but what if I want those tags rendered in the column? I only want to remove them from the filter dropdown.

I feel a bit foolish for not realizing that. Sorry! Alright, again, drop the call for paste0 (as I said in my earlier comment) and when creating the DT, add %>% formatStyle(columns = c("Species"), fontWeight = 'bold')

I guess I should have been a little more specific about my ultimate goal - I'm planning on using image tags and icons, not just the strong tag. I'll edit by question - sorry about that.

Changing the display of the cells without changing their value is the purpose of the columnwise option render.

library(DT)
library(fontawesome)


dat <- iris

js <- c(
    "function (data, type, row, meta) {",
    "  if(type === 'display') {",
    "    var icon;",
    "    if(data === 'setosa') {",
    sprintf("icon = '%s'", as.character(fa_i("cat"))),
    "    } else if(data === 'versicolor') {",
    sprintf("icon = '%s'", as.character(fa_i("dog"))),
    "    } else if(data === 'virginica') {",
    sprintf("icon = '%s'", as.character(fa_i("fish"))),
    "    }",
    "    return '<em>' + '&nbsp;' + icon + data + '</em>';",
    "  } else {",
    "    return data;",
    "  }",
    "}"
)

dtable <- datatable(
    dat,
    rownames = TRUE,
    filter = "top",
    options = 
        list(
            columnDefs =
                list(
                    list(
                        targets = list(5),
                        render = JS(js)
                    )
                )
        )
    )

deps <- dtable$dependencies
deps <- c(deps, list(fa_html_dependency()))
dtable$dependencies <- deps
dtable

In a Shiny app, this last step should not be necessary:
deps <- dtable$dependencies
deps <- c(deps, list(fa_html_dependency()))
dtable$dependencies <- deps

